# Android : Text disappears frequently in webview when LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE is set

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to add a webview within scrollview which can display static HTML text with transparent background. Here is the code

```
        WebView descr = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        descr.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        descr.loadData(desc, "text/html", "utf-8");
        descr.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

If I don't set setLayerType value, I can see the text correctly. However it adds flickering effect when the scrolling is done. If setLayerType line is added, text for some of the pages disappears. Here is how my layout looks like

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:contentDescription="@id/title"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This problem occurs when i install .apk file on my mobile and not on emulator. I am using android version 4.1.2. Can someone let me know what need to be done so that the text would be displayed without flickering effect and with transparent background?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find any solution. if yes please share it

Comment: I changed the webview with TextView. I did formatting of the text by  implementing Html.TagHandler. This seems to be a uncommon issue. I am not sure if its specific to a device or specific to android version.

Comment: I thought i was the only one who faced this issue and this must be problem with my device. However as you are facing same issue, i have reported the same at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60484 Please let me know which device are you using.

Answer (score 3):

please add #android:layerType="software"# to the WebView and all the container until ScrollView. on Android4.4, it works for me.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layerType="software"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layerType="software"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:contentDescription="@id/title"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            />

        <WebView
            android:layerType="software"
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem, and I resolved it; webview in scrollview and webview setlayertype software, so you need setlayertype software for scrollview; like below:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layerType="software"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title" >
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: scrollview is not needed because a webview can automatically scroll

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in reverse; things in the webview disappeared when the text input box was clicked and the soft-keyboard scrolled up (on my Sony phone).

These are all the settings I used that had a direct effect on the webview:

- in Manifest, in the activity declaration, to make the webview pan up as the keyboard scrolls up: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`
- in root of layout, to allow the webview to pan as the keyboard scrolls up: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`
- in webview, to disable hardware acceleration to prevent webpage form items from disappearing as the keyboard scrolled up: `android:layerType="software"`